# REST Service with third party OAuth2

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, client-server

I'm building a REST server and a client for it. Now I need to embed some third party oauth2 authentication. Right now I'm directing the user to the server, let him authenticate to the service and then I redirect to the client, somewhat like this:

Client: Not Authenticated -> Server -> Redirect to Third Party -> Redirect to Server -> Redirect to App.

Then I store a cookie on the client to identify the user (the cookie is sent using withCredentials and CORS).

My problem now is what should I do with re-authentication when the token expires? Since the client and server only communicate through json, I would have to initiate the full authentication process again and therefore the user would lose all state in the app. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get around this problem? Is it better to do authentication on the client side and store the access token on the server or something?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have done is the proper way to get OAuth **access_token**. And your **access_token** is temporary so can expire.

I think you can do either of these :

1. Check if Authorization Server ( which you use for getting token) provides option to get a longer duration token using your **access_token**. This is suggested in OAuth 2 specification as well.
2. Try to store User's state without using session.

Comment: Right, so I guess there is no better solution. Getting a longer token doesn't really remove the problem but it makes the re-authentication process less frequent. Storing state is of course possible (since everything is already client side), but also a hard problem. I was thinking of maybe using window.open() for the re-authentication flow, but it also isn't optimal. How about an iframe?

Comment: storing state is not so hard; you can store user's state information in your app. i haven't tried with iframe but sounds worth trying.

Comment: it depends on what kind of state we are talking about. I mean the current state of the application, down to the last click by the user. That is definitely not a trivial problem if the application is sufficiently complex.